# How to get the last visible row within a div container?

Tags: jquery

I have a  within a  container. The table rows overflow within this div container. Given this,

```
    <div id="tableDiv"> 
      <table> 
       <tbody id="topTbody">
          <tr data-index="1"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="2"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="3"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="4"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="5"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="6"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="7"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="8"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="9"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
          <tr data-index="10"><td>dfsfad</td><td>afadfaf</td><td>afafd</td></tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I need to get the last visible row within the div container. 
I tried this:
                alert($("#topTbody tr:visible").last().attr("data-index"));

And it gives me the last index of 10 (row) but index 10 is not visible within the div. Index 5 is the last visible row within the div container. How can I get the last visible row within the div container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but you could try something along these lines

```
var divHeight = $('#tableDiv').height(); // or outerHeight()?
var visibleHeight = 0;
var visibleIndex = 0;
$.each('#topTbody tr', function(index, row) {
  visibleHeight += $(row).height();
  if (visibleHeight > divHeight) {
    // Its not visible so get the index and exit
    visibleIndex = index;
    return false
  }
```

You might need to consider partially visible items

Comment: Could not get this code to work but it does give me a good starting point to work from.. thanks